# getting int not callable while using logger in python

Tags: python, int

I am very new to python. When i try to run the following code getting int object not callable. I found lot of posts in the internet but none of them worked. please help me out.

Code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler(timzone='Asia/Kolkata') 
    scheduler.add_job(schedule_creditCnts_job, 'cron',  minute=2, hour=23) 
    logging.INFO("starting scheduler")
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../util/JobScheduler", line 18, in <module>
    logging.INFO("starting scheduler")
TypeError: 'int' object is not callabl
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`logging.INFO` is a int representing the log level INFO. Use `logging.info`. Remember, python is case sensitive

```
logging.info("starting scheduler")
```

Answer (score 1):

`logging.INFO` is a constant from the logging package.

You want to use `logging.info`, which is the method that logs info-level messages.

```
>>> logging.INFO
20
>>> logging.info
<function info at 0x7f0a2762d500>
```